# Modifying a record in binary file

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define etudian_num 400
struct etudiant{
    char nom[10];
    float moy;
};

void SaisirEtudiant(struct etudiant E,FILE *ficheierEtudiant) {
    ficheierEtudiant = fopen("C:/Users/Ayoub/Desktop/TDTP/Ex1/Etudiant.dat","wb");
    char rep;
    do {
        fseek(ficheierEtudiant, 0, SEEK_END);

        printf("Saisir nom etudiant a saisir: ");
        scanf("%s",&E.nom);
        printf("Saisir son Moyen: ");
        scanf("%f",&E.moy);
        fwrite (&E, sizeof(struct etudiant), 1,ficheierEtudiant);
        if(fwrite!=0) {
            printf("\n\nEtudaint Ajouter avec succees !\n\n");
        }
        printf("Voulez Vouz Saisir un autre Etudiant (O,N): ");
        scanf(" %c",&rep);
    } while(toupper(rep)!='N');
    fclose(ficheierEtudiant);    
}

void AjoutEtudian(struct etudiant E,FILE *ficheierEtudiant) {    
    ficheierEtudiant=fopen("C:/Users/Ayoub/Desktop/TDTP/Ex1/Etudiant.dat","ab+");
    printf("Saisir Nom de Nouveau Etudiant: ");
    scanf("%s",&E.nom);
    printf("Saisir Son Moyen: ");
    scanf("%f",&E.moy);
    fwrite (&E, sizeof(struct etudiant), 1,ficheierEtudiant);
    printf("Saisir de nouveau Etudiant avec Success ! ");
    fclose(ficheierEtudiant);
}

void EcrireListeEtudiant(struct etudiant E, FILE* fichierEtudiant) {
    fichierEtudiant=fopen("C:/Users/Ayoub/Desktop/TDTP/Ex1/Etudiant.dat","r+");
    while(fread(&E,sizeof(struct etudiant),1,fichierEtudiant)){
    printf("Nom Etudiant: %s| Moyen= %.2f \n", E.nom, E.moy);}
    fclose(fichierEtudiant);
}

void ModifierEtudiant(struct etudiant E,FILE* fichierEtudiant) {
    fichierEtudiant=fopen("C:/Users/Ayoub/Desktop/TDTP/Ex1/Etudiant.dat","rb+");
    char RechercheEtudiant[10];
    float NouveauMoyen;
    printf("Saisir Le nom de letudiant a modifier son Moyen: ");
    scanf("%s",&RechercheEtudiant);
    float Moyenancianen=0.0;
    while(fread(&E,sizeof(struct etudiant),1,fichierEtudiant)) {
        if(strcmp(E.nom,RechercheEtudiant)==0) {
            Moyenancianen=E.moy;
            printf("Saisir Nouveau Moyen pour ",E.nom);
            scanf("%f",&NouveauMoyen);
            E.moy=NouveauMoyen;
            printf("\n\nMoyen Ancien = %.2f , Nouveau Moyen = %.2f\n\n",Moyenancianen,NouveauMoyen);
        }else {
            printf("Nom invalid !");
        }    
    }
    fclose(fichierEtudiant);    
}

void Menu() {
    printf("Press: \n");
    printf("\t\n1-Pour Ajouter un Nouveau List des Etudiant\n");
    printf("\t\n2-pour imprimer Liste des Etudiant \n");
    printf("\t\n3-pour Ajouter un Nouveau Etudiant \n");
    printf("\t\n4-pour Modifier Moyen d un Etudain\n");
    printf("\t\n5-pour imprimer Liste de Menu\n");
    printf("\t\n6-Pour Quitter \n");
} 

int main()
{ printf("\t\t***************************Programme de Gestion des Etudiants***************************\n\n\n\n");
   FILE *fichierEtudiant;
    struct etudiant E;
    int choice;
    int num;
    int quit=0;
    Menu();
    while(quit==0){
        printf("\nSaisir Votre Choix: ");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice){
        case 1:
            SaisirEtudiant(E,fichierEtudiant);
            break;
        case 2:
            EcrireListeEtudiant(E,fichierEtudiant);
            break;
        case 3:
            AjoutEtudian(E,fichierEtudiant);
            break;

        case 4:
            ModifierEtudiant(E,fichierEtudiant);
            break;
        case 5:
            Menu();
            break;
        case 6:
            quit =1;
            printf("A bientot.....");
            break;
        }
    }   
}
```

The program is about to store a List of students and their marks. Everything works well until the modify part (ModifierEtudiant method). I'm reading the name from the user so I can later check if it does exist in the binary file. If it is found, I demand the user to input a new mark and it seems that it doesn't take the new mark value.

[image]

Comment: If you checked the return codes *properly* from your calls, you'd have a better idea where the problem lies.

Comment: it is in the "ModifierEtudiant" method

Comment: The function `scanf()` returns a helpful value. Do you know that value in the problematic case? You ignore it at your own risk.

Comment: Did you try to output the read value of NouveauMoyen? Make sure that it is initialised with a special value that you will be able to tell apart from any possibly entered value.

Comment: Probably not related to your core problem, but in all your calls, the _ficiher_ and the _étudiant_ should be local variables, not arguments.

Comment: If I am to guess, your scanf for an int in main() leaves a newline in the input stream, which terminates the attempt to enter a students name early and empty.

Comment: I've tried to print it and it prints correctly

Comment: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You are not restricting input lengths: this `scanf("%s",&RechercheEtudiant);` begs to fall over. It should be `scanf("%9s", RechercheEtudiant);` along with some error checking.

Comment: i've fixed the the input length but still not getting the new mark value

Comment: "it doesn't take the new mark value." -- What does that mean? The new mark does not show up when you print it with as `"Nouveau Moyen = %.2f"`? That's the only location where you use it, because you don't update `E` in `main` -- the one in `ModifierEtudiant` is a copy. And you don't update the file, either.

Comment: In function `ModifierEtudiant` there is no `fseek` and `fwrite` to put the modified `struct` back into the file.

Comment: Weather Vane yeah you are right but i've thought about the fseek but it takes 3 argument how can i point it in position of the record in the file ?

Comment: guys check the image i've added now

Comment: Please do not post images.  Rather copy/paste the text into the question

Answer (score 0):

Had to control the pointer ! 
fseek(fichierEtudiant,-(long)sizeof(E),1);
fwrite (&E, sizeof(E), 1,fichierEtudiant);